# Why does the graph of $y^2=1-\frac{4x^{10^{12}}}{\pi^2}$ look so much like a square?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

> I want to know why the equation $y^2=1-\dfrac{4x^{10^{12}}}{\pi^2}$ gives an approximate square. (See the figure below.)

---

**Background**

I was just playing around with functions and I wanted to see if $y=\left|\sin\bigg(\dfrac{\pi x}{2}\bigg)\right|$ (radians) would give a semicircle for the interval $[0,2]$ as the distance of $(1,0)$ is the same from $(0,0)$, $(2,0)$ and $(1,1)$, all of which will lie on the curve. The equation of a unit semicircle with its centre at $(1,0)$ is $y=\sqrt{2x-x^2}$.

I know that the curves of both the equations don't resemble each other much but I still thought of approximating the sine function using this because I thought that it could still be combined with another approximation to make a better approximation. Anyway, I did it and for $\phi=x~\mathrm{radians}$, the value of $\sin\phi$ can to be approximately $\dfrac2\pi\sqrt{\pi x-x^2}$. It looked like a semi-ellipse and so I verified it to find that it was a semi-ellipse. I thought of using this to derive the equation for an ellipse with it's centre at the origin and the value of $a$ and $b$ being $\dfrac\pi2$ and $1$ respectively.

The equation came out to be : $y^2 = 1 - \dfrac{4x^2}{\pi^2}$

---

Finally, I thought of playing with this equation and changed the exponent of $x$. I observed that as I increased the power, keeping it even, the figure got closer and closer to a square.

$y^2=1-\dfrac{4x^{10^{12}}}{\pi^2}$ gave a good approximation of a square. For the exponent of $x$ being some power of $10$ greater than $10^{12}$, a part of the curve began to disappear.

[image: Figure]

I want to know why this equation gives an approximate square.

**Note :** I would like to inform you that I have no experience with conic sections.

Thanks!

Comment: @ZAhmed, OP was talking about $y^2=1-\dfrac{4x^{10^{12}}}{\pi^2}$

Comment: Try $x^{10^6}+y^{10^6}=1$

Comment: Try graphing by hand, not with a graphing calculator or a computer algebra system. I think it will be very apparent that, unless you use a value of $x$ that is extremely close to (but less than) $1,$ the value of $\dfrac{4x^{10^{12}}}{\pi^2}$ is essentially equal $0.$

Comment: So, for those values of $x$ not so close to $1$ or $-1$ and lying between the two, the value of $\dfrac{4^{10^{12}}}{\pi^2}$ is essentially $0$ and so, the value of $1-\dfrac{4^{10^{12}}}{\pi^2}$ becomes about $1$ and so, for those values of $x$, the equation becomes $y^2=1$ which means that the point $(x,1)$ and $(x,-1)$ are plotted. So, what's your point?

Comment: Did you actually try plotting the points? You'll essentially get two horizontal segments of points when $x$ is between $-1$ and $1$ (unless $x$ is very, very close to $-1$ or $1),$ and when $x$ is very, very close to $-1$ or $1,$ then the points graphed (as you approach $-1$ and $1)$ very, very rapidly move from essentially $y=0$ to essentially $y=\pm 1,$ which essentially gives you two vertical segments of points, one located at $x=-1$ and the other located at $x=1.$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Sorry, but isn't that basically approximately a square? I think that this is your answer to the question...

Comment: hi Dave sorry I waq a bit busy these daises I will send it today. Thanks for your kindness.

Answer (score 3):

First, let's determine the possible values for $x.$ Thanks to @Intelligenti pauca for pointing out this oversight in my original answer, which caused significant *qualitative* errors in my original answer.

Since $y^2$ is non-negative, we have:

$$ 1 \; - \; \frac{4x^{{10}^{12}}}{{\pi}^2} \; \geq \; 0 $$

$$ x^{{10}^{12}} \; \leq \; \frac{{\pi}^2}{4} $$

$$  -\left(\frac{{\pi}^2}{4}\right)^{{10}^{-12}} \; \leq \; x \; \leq \; \left(\frac{{\pi}^2}{4}\right)^{{10}^{-12}}  $$

$$  -1.0000000000009031654105793 \ldots \; \leq \; x \; \leq \; 1.0000000000009031654105793 \ldots $$

For the decimal approximation used above, see [this WolframAlpha computation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28%28pi%29%5E2%29%2F4%29%5E%2810%5E%28-12%29%29).

Note that for $x = \pm \left(\frac{{\pi}^2}{4}\right)^{{10}^{-12}} \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \; \pm \beta,$ we have $y^2 = 0,$ and hence $y = 0.$

When $x = \pm \, 0.999999,$ we find that [$\;y^2 \approx 1 \; – \; {10}^{-434,000}\;$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%284*%280.999999%29%5E%28%2810%29%5E%2812%29%29%29%2F%28%28pi%29%5E2%29) and [$\;y \approx \pm \left(1 \; – \; {10}^{-217,000}\right)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%28%284*%280.999999%29%5E%28%2810%29%5E%2812%29%29%29%2F%28%28pi%29%5E2%29%29). The table below shows the result of several similar calculations.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
x & y^2 & y \\ \hline & & \\ \hline 0 & 1 & \pm \, 1 \\ \hline
 \pm \, 0.9 & 1 - {10}^{-45,700,000,000} & \pm \left(1 - {10}^{-22,900,000,000}\right) \\ \hline
 \pm \left(1 - {10}^{-6}\right) \; = \;\pm \, 0.999999 & 1 - {10}^{-434,000} & \pm \left(1 - {10}^{-217,000}\right) \\ \hline
 \pm \left(1 - {10}^{-10}\right)  \; = \;\pm \, 0.9999999999 & 1 \; - \; 2.5\times{10}^{-44}  & \pm \left(1 \; - \; 1.2\times{10}^{-22}\right) \\ \hline
 \pm\left(1 - {10}^{-12}\right) & 0.8509 \ldots  & \pm \, 0.9224\ldots \\ \hline
 \pm \left(1 - {10}^{-15}\right) & 0.5951 \ldots & \pm \, 0.7714\ldots \\ \hline \pm \, 1 & 0.5947 \ldots & \pm \, 0.7711\ldots \\ \hline \pm \, 1.000000000000903 & 0.000165 \ldots & \pm \, 0.012860 \ldots \\ \hline \pm \, \beta & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Thus, using the fact that $y^2$ is a **decreasing function** of $|x|$ for $-\beta < x < \beta,$ it follows that the points $(x,y)$ on the graph form two nearly horizonal arcs and two nearly vertical arcs. The upper arc is concave down, has endpoints $(- \beta, 0)$ and $(\beta, 0),$ reaches a maximum height above the $x$-axis at the point $(0,1),$ and visually it will look like a horizontal segment for $-\beta \approx -1 < x < 1 \approx \beta$ along with a pair of vertical segments, one at $x = 1 \approx \beta$ and the other at $x = -1 \approx -\beta.$ The lower arc is the reflection of the upper arc about the $x$-axis.

Visually, the upper arc will look like the upper horizontal and two vertical sides of a rectangle whose vertices are $(-1,0)$ and $(-1,1)$ and $(1,1)$ and $(1,0).$ Visually, the lower arc will look like the lower horizontal and two vertical sides of a rectangle whose vertices are $(-1,-1)$ and $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$ and $(1,-1).$ Together, these two arcs will visually look like the four sides of a square whose vertices are $(-1,-1)$ and $(-1,1)$ and $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1).$

Comment: Why do you restrict $x$ in the interval $[-1,1]$? As I wrote in my answer, $x$ can also be slightly larger than $1$.

Comment: Hi Dave sorry, to bother do you have another link for this odf about limitd .?  This sheet by Dave Renfro that I found online was beyond helpful! http://mathforum.org/kb/servlet/JiveServlet/download/206-1874348-6544585-538002/seq3.pdf

Comment: @Aryadeva: That link doesn't work anymore and I don't know what it was, but if you tell me, and also give me a rough idea of what you're interested in, I can send you .pdf files of various related manuscripts, handouts, etc. I have by email. I'll need your email address, which you can give me by sending me an email. My email address can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/13130/dave-l-renfro?tab=profile).

Comment: Thanks a lot Dave I guess it"s some notes of yours about usefull Limits. The link was posted here on MSE https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/686665/list-of-common-or-useful-limits-of-sequences-and-series

Comment: @Aryadeva: I still don't know which one it is, but I have several such handouts that I wrote in the late 1990s (and reused a few times in the early 2000s), which I can send once I have your email address.

Comment: I will send an email tomorrow Thanks a lot for your kindness Dave.

Comment: @Aryadeva: About 24 hours ago I went through my teaching files from the mid 1990s to mid 2000s (4 different schools/colleges/universities; looked through my precalculus and calculus 1, 2, 3 files), found 19 handouts that seem as if they could be of use, and made .pdf files from the original [SWP](https://www.mackichan.com/index.html?products/whichproduct.html~mainFrame) versions, but I haven't heard from you yet.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rectangle, because for $x=0$ we get $|y|=1$, but for $y=0$ we obtain
$$
x=\root{10^{12}}\of{\pi^2\over4}\approx
1.0000000000009031654.
$$
For a square, you'd better replace ${4\over\pi^2}$ with $1$.

Comment: Um, didn't I ask "Why does the graph.....look so much **like a square**"? I really don't think this answers my question...

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu This explains that the term $4/\pi^2$ in your formula has nothing to do with a square, and could be replaced by any other (not too large) number, possibly just by $1$. As explained in the comments, the graph resembles a square just because $x^{10^{12}}$ is very near to $0$ when $x\in(0,1-\epsilon)$, with $\epsilon$ very small.

Answer (score 1):

HINT

$y=\pm 1$ is clearly a tendency around $x=0$ and the

$y=\log[(4/\pi)^2  x^{m}] $  tends to pass through $(x=1, x=-1)$ as  $y\rightarrow 0$

Answer (score 1):

This is related to what happens with the graphs of very high powers of $x,$
which in turn is related to exponential growth and decay.

Graph $y = x^2.$ Notice that the curve goes through $(0,0)$ at its low point, and goes through $(-1,1)$ on the left and $(1,1)$ on the right.
And the graph has a tiny nearly level section very near the bottom.

Try $y = x^4.$ It's somewhat like $y=x^2$, but the sides are steeper at
$(-1,1)$ and $(1,1)$ and the bottom is much flatter.

Try $y = x^{10}$. Steeper sides, flatter bottom than $x^4.$

As you try higher and higher powers of $x,$ you get a larger and larger "flat" part at the bottom of the curve.
This part isn't really flat, it's just that for any number $x$ with $|x|<1,$
if you look at $x^n$ and increase the exponent $n$ you have a process of exponential decay where $x^n$ approaches zero. At some exponent the value of $x^n$ will be so small that you cannot see the difference between $x^n$ and zero on the graph.

For values of $x$ closer to $\pm 1$, $x^n$ decays slower and it takes a higher value of $n$ before $x^n$ gets close enough to zero to be indistinguishable from zero by your eye. But if you take really large values of $n$, such as $10^{12},$ the numbers near $\pm1$ for which $x^n$ is **not** visually indistinguishable from zero are so close to $\pm1$ that they are visually indistinguishable from $1$ and the graph looks like it has straight vertical sides there.
In fact even at $n = 1000$ the graph looks pretty square at the bottom to me.

Now flip the graph over by taking $y = 1 - x^n$ for a very large value of $n.$
It still has that rectangular shape, but the flat level part is at $y = 1$
and the rest is below that, passing through $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$.

Now take $y = \sqrt{1 - x^n}.$ If $n$ is large enough this still looks rectangular, but the parts of the graph below the $x$ axis have disappeared because negative numbers do not have real square roots.

If you now square both sides, $y^2 = {1 - x^n},$
you get the same result above the $x$ axis,
but since $(-y)^2 = y^2$ you get two symmetric values of $y$ for each value of $x,$
that is, the graph above the $x$ axis is mirrored below the $x$ axis,
forming what looks like a square.

Multiplying $x^n$ by some positive constant $a$, as in $y^2 = {1 - ax^n},$
makes the graph wider or narrower in the $x$ direction.
That is, you are graphing $y^2 = {1 - (a^{1/n}x)^n},$
so the graph is scaled by a factor of $a^{-1/n}$ in width.
If $a$ is not too large (for example, $a = 4/\pi^2$) and $n$ is very large,
$a^{-1/n}$ is extremely near $1$ (as other answers have pointed out).

> For the exponent of $x$ being some power of $10$ greater than $10^{12}$, a part of the curve began to disappear.

I had a similar experience with extremely high powers of $x$, using the graphing calculator at Desmos.com. I suspect this is a limitation of the size of number that the calculator can deal with, or perhaps the horizontal step size (graph so steep that the software cannot increment $x$ slowly enough to plot a continuous curve).